# Set columns names for a new Excel workbook

Tags: vba, excel

I create a new workbook programmatically using the following code :

```
    'Adding a new workbook
    Workbooks.Add

    'Saving the new workbook
    ActiveWorkbook.SaveAs newFilePath

    'Closing the new workbook
    ActiveWorkbook.Close
```

I would like to know how to set columns names, in other words how to write in the workbook, before closing it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Reference the new workbook using a variable, and subsequently interact with the variable name. See example:

```
Sub ttt()
    Dim wb As Workbook

    Set wb = Workbooks.Add
    wb.ActiveSheet.Range("A1").Value = "Hello"
End Sub
```

Comment: I get a "Run Time Error '424' object required" error message with your solution.

Comment: Can you post the entirety of your code, specifically focusing on which line is throwing the error?

Comment: Actually the error came from elsewhere, it works now, thanks :)